# Second usage of verb redundant?

Tags: word-usage, syntactic-analysis

Is the second usage of execute necessary, or can it be omitted?

I find the second usage to be redundant but i'm not sure if it is correct to omit it. Which one is more concise, if both are correct?

> An unaware user cannot accidentally execute code that he did not
>   intend to [execute].

Comment: but the phrase itself is redundant too. "accidentally" and "without intend" are the same thing. You could leave it as: "An unaware user cannot accidentally execute code", and you'll have the same meaning

Comment: Since "Accidentally" means "without intending to", the entire that-phrase is redundant, and "An unaware user cannot accidentally execute code" is sufficient.

Comment: You are right. Still, if the phrase weren't redundant in itself, would the word be redundant or is it needed?

Comment: We would not say "An unaware user cannot accidentally execute code that he did not intend to execute." Better if you don't mind ending with _to_: "An unaware user cannot accidentally execute code without intending to." As for your question of conciseness, you answered that by saying one version has fewer words.

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not redundant.

> An unaware user cannot accidentally execute code that he did not intend to execute.

In technical statements like the one above, it is advisable to specify all the details (clear the ambiguity) that could otherwise be misinterpreted.

Comment: So technically the second execute can be omitted but should not be in this case since it is a technical document and clarity goes above fance wording?

Comment: This answer is wrong. It is certainly redundant, in that the meaning is the same with or without it. The fact that it might be desirable to include it (whether for clarity or for prosody) does not make it not redundant.

Comment: A better way to use redundancy than to repeat yourself is to use contrast for emphasis: "You must pay in cash, _not by check or credit_." In such a case, the extra words may seem redundant but counter obvious questions like "What about a credit card?'"  "An unaware user cannot accidentally execute code, only _deliberately_."